# Solution in terms of singular values and singular vectors

Tags: matrix-equations, svd

Given $(A^{T}A+L^{T}L)x=A^{T}b$ where $L=\alpha I$, I am asked to find $x$ in terms of $\alpha$ and singular values and vectors of $A$.

If I try using $A=U\Sigma V^{T}$ I eventually get to $(V\Sigma^{2}V^{T}+\alpha^{2}I)x=V\Sigma U^{T}b$ where I get stuck.

Since I am supposed to find $x$ in terms of singular values and vectors of $A$ I've also tried using $A=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sigma_{i}\mathbf{u_{i}v_{i}}^{T}$ but I am not really sure how to proceed after substituting in the above relationship.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if I am not mistaken the first term is $\sum \sigma_i^2 I$. Then one divides both sides by $\sum \sigma_i^2+\alpha^2$.

Comment: How can I prove that the first term is $\sum \sigma_i^2 I$? Is $V\Sigma^{2}V^{T}$ the equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sigma_{i}^{2}\mathbf{v_{i}v_{i}}^{T}$?

Comment: Let $U S V^T:=V\Sigma^2V^T$. Apply your formula to $U S V^T$ and at the end replace with $V\Sigma^2V^T$. So $U S V^T=\sum \sigma_i^2 u_i v_i^T$, and here the diagonal elements of $S$ are then $\sigma_i^2$...